# Отрок был послушлив, прилежен и(,) сколько мог по своему возрасту(,) помогал родителям. Нужны ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые

Здесь придаточная степени и меры или что-то вроде цельного выражения: сколько мог (значит, не отделяется запятыми)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отрок был послушлив (послушен), прилежен и (столько), **сколько мог по своему возрасту**, 
помогал родителям.

Придаточное предложение выделяется запятыми.

Цельное выражение: Отрок был послушлив, прилежен и **помогал сколько мог** 
родителям.

Разница в распространенности оборота и предложения.

Примечание.  Повтор корневой основы: мог, помогал.